# Is it standard practice to use standard std::exception subclasses for your own purposes?

Tags: c++, exception

If I have code like:

```
std::vector<foo> bar;
...fill up bar...
if (bar.size() < 5)
{
    throw std::out_of_range("Not enough foos in the bar");
}
```

Does the standard allow and expect such reuse, or is this frowned upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: You are free to throw something not derived from `std::exception` but that makes it hard for people to write generic `catch` clauses (other than `catch(...)`) and to print out any meaningful information about the exception (the `.what()` part).

Find the standard exception best describing what you are about to throw and use that. You may also inherit it to make your own exception.

Answer (score 1):

Not for their own purposes so much but if you want to use them as they were originally intended then that's fine.

Your example is possibly a reasonable use of `std::out_of_range` but throwing `std::bad_weak_ptr` for example would not be appropriate. The reference for [`std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) states:

> reports errors that are consequence of attempt to access elements out of defined range.

So if you are about to access `bar[5]` then the exception is appropriate.

Ultimately what matters is if you are making a library you should document which exceptions you throw and why.